# Why does this query get all users?

Tags: mysql, sql

so i have this query to determine whether or not it should count towards one entry in a table or not. however, it grabs all the users entries and disobays my

```
"dc.userid = ". $user ."
```

in an above query i use to gather what the user actually has inputted. and that works fine. however, when i exclude something it fetches all the entries from every user.
i will provide more code if noone can solve it from here. but i ive set $total above. in my case its 4. one entry should be excluded. but it fetches all entries which arent user = 1 and excludes them. in this case 11, which makes the $total variable -8 and not 3 as it should be. why is that?

```
$query3 = "SELECT IFNULL(dc.amount, 0) amount, dt.drop_id, dc.drop_id, dc.boss_id, dc.userid, dt.excl
FROM droptable dt
LEFT JOIN dropcounter dc
ON dt.boss_id = dc.boss_id AND dc.drop_id = dt.drop_id AND dc.userid = ". $user ."
WHERE dt.excl = 1 AND dc.userid = ". $user ."";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query3);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



foreach($result as $row){
    $amount = $row['amount'];
    echo $amount;
    echo "<br>";
    if (empty($amount)){}
    else {
    $total -= $amount;
    }
    }
    echo $total;
```

Comment: Good that you're preparing the statement. But why not do it properly?

Comment: because im a newbie in pdo and i didnt think it was necesary if you're just passing numbers.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but you shouldn't have `dc.userid = $user` in the WHERE clause, only the ON clause.

Comment: Can you show some sample input data, the results you're trying to get, and what you're getting instead? And make a sqlfiddle so we can try to work with it.

Comment: @barmar http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8a5d where excl is 1, that one should be excluded from it. there are 14 total loggings, but after this query it should be left with 12. tell me if this isnt enough info

Comment: I tried running your query in the fiddle, but there's no `boss_id` in the tables. You also changed `userid` to `user_id` but that was an easy fix.

Comment: When I took `dt.boss_id = dc.boss_id` out of the query, it just returned 1 row.

Comment: @barmar im sorry. i threw it together when i was extremely tired. i fixed it, and added more users (since that was the problem) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cfce2

Comment: I still get only 1 row: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cfce2/2. If you're doing a different query, please show it in the fiddle.